# Recommendations on pyranometer In-amp design

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm planning to build a [pyranometer](http://matrix-solar.com/_sub_files/images/mk1-spec.pdf) amp based on the [AD620](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad620.pdf) In-Amp, at this point I would ask your knowledge on the following details:

a) Apart from using a 1.5v dry battery with a (huge?) voltage divider, is there another way to simulate the microvolt/milivolt signal level for the INA input? (I want to test the device by comparing the input Vs the voltage output using a oscilloscope and/or millivoltmeter).

b) Should I use a low-pass filter (cut-off freq around 40 Hz or less, to leave out the 50/60 Hz AC Hum) after the INA-amp or between the pyranometer and the INA-amp?

Answer (score 0):

A voltage divider will work fine. For example, you can use a 100 ohm pot paralleled with 10 ohms metal film and 150 ohms metal film in series with battery or other 1.5V supply. It will drift a bit if you use a single battery directly, but you could use two batteries in series and a regulator such as an [MCP1702](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/268/22008d-45809.pdf).

It's not clear to me that you actually need an instrumentation amplifier. A simple non-inverting amplifier may be better, but it depends on your circuit arrangement and if there is any wiring to the sensor, and so on. A low pass filter is probably a good idea in any case.

A DMM with a 200mV scale is a good way to measure the input signal.

Comment: a) Thanks for your suggestion about the voltage divider, I will post a schematic later only to make sure I understand you idea correctly.

b) The expected output from the Pyranometer is  Roughly around 70 mV for about 1000 W/m2, I guess the INA gain should be around 20 to have a good match with a 3.3V range ADC.